# How do I resolve, browser disconnected error running testcafe test1.js on firefox:headless with SUSE

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, e2e-testing, suse, testcafe

Setting up testcafe on a new version of SUSE OS.
Running the testcafe getting started a test on SUSE using firefox:headless I get a long pause then the error :

testcafe firefox:headless  test1.js --reporter=xunit

"ERROR The Firefox 66.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues."

Testcafe version:
0.23.3

Linux version:
NAME="SUSE" VERSION="12 SP4" uname -a = "4.12.14-94.41-default"

Firefox version:
66.0.2

node.js version:
v10.15.3

The same works fine with firefox if I don't run headless, the tests execute successfully without any error if I point the DISPLAY to ViewNow which allows X windows to DISPLAY the browser running on my PC, but I need headless for our automation framework.

Following the instructions on https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/ I can also use 
firefox -screenshot http://www.microfocus.com
which runs the browser in headless mode to access a Web page and captures a .png which shows the connection is successful so headless firefox can get to Web pages.

I have an older version of SUSE, testcafe, firefox which runs headless and works, so I know this used to work:
Test cafe version:
testcafe -v 0.18.6

Linux version:
NAME="SUSE" VERSION="12 SP2" uname -a = "4.4.21-69-default"

Firefox version:
58.0.2

node.js version:
v8.9.4

Expected result:
 Running tests in:
 - Firefox 66.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0

Getting Started
 ✓ My first test

1 passed (1s)

Comment: Could you please try to connect Headless Firefox to TestCafe as a remote browser: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#remote-browsers? You can start Firefox in a separate terminal window after executing the "testcafe remote ..." command.

Comment: I stated firefox in background pointing the DISPLAY to my PC as I don't have access to an X windows Display on the SUSE box.
Ran 
testcafe remote firefox:headless test1.js --reporter=xunit
Pasted the URL into the firefox browser and got :

Comment: Unable to connect

Firefox cant establish a connection to the server at 10.120.79.52:41515.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computers network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

There is no firewall preventing access.

Comment: Perhaps this is something to do with the installation of Firefox on the SuSE Linux server. Although, as you say, having the DISPLAY set to your PC running an X server and not running in headless mode loads up the Firefox browser on your PC and the test script runs through ok.

I came across this on Mozilla's site and wondering if it's the same problem of running in headless mode on Linux for which the bug report mentioned (bug 1372998) was raised -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode#Troubleshooting_and_further_help
(raised 2 years ago!)

Comment: Last entry in that bug was, a year ago, when Mozilla said "There are currently no immediate plans to work on this." 
What I don't understand is, if it is this issue, how come my older system of SUSE, firefox and Testcafe works?

Comment: Please try to perform the following steps:


1) Execute the `testcafe --hostname localhost --ports 9000,9001 remote test1.js` command in a remote session with your SUSE box.
  

2) Keep this session opened and start a new remote session. Execute `firefox -headless http://localhost:9000/browser/connect` in the new session. Collect and post here all terminal output produced by Firefox.

Comment: In session 1 I get:
Using locally installed version of TestCafe.
Connecting 1 remote browser(s)...
Navigate to the following URL from each remote browser.
Connect URL: http://localhost:9000/browser/connect
CONNECTED Firefox 66.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0
Running tests in:
- Firefox 66.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0

Getting Started

Comment: Then I connect with session 2, I get:

*** You are running in headless mode.

Then after about 5 minutes I get :

[Parent 6837, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 726
Killed

Comment: At which point session 1 recieves:
ERROR The Firefox 66.0.0 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.

Type "testcafe -h" for help.

Comment: It looks like a problem with Marionette client that is used inside TestCafe to communicate with Firefox.
Please try to reproduce the problem with the latest Firefox and TestCafe versions and inform us about your results.

Comment: I am already using the latest testcafe and jsnode, (see above).
 The firefox is one version old 66.0.2 not 66.0.3, I'll install the latest and try again.

Comment: Problem solved. The installation I was using was not being updated because testcafe linked to an old .js
Testcafe installed in /home1/hub/testbin/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/testcafe
was a symbolic link to 
../lib/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js*

Comment: This version never got updated from 0.0.23 when nmp install -g testcafe ran
instead this was updated as 
/home1/hub/testbin/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js but that never got execute permissions:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 *** users 207 Oct 26  1985 testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 *** users  59 Oct 26  1985 testcafe.js*
(not sure why they are dated 1985 either??)
I added execute permissions to testcafe.js and now testcafe -v gives 1.1.3
and headless is working.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @Cuffy,

Thank you for the update. I'm happy to hear that you have figured out how to resolve the issue. 

You might want to post your findings as an Answer to your own question, so other users may refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Testcafe installation issue caused older testcafe to be invoked after testcafe was updated:
Testcafe installed in /home1/{id}/testbin/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/bin/testcafe
was a symbolic link to 
../lib/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js*
This version never got updated from 0.0.23 when nmp install -g testcafe ran
instead this was updated as 
/home1/{id}/testbin/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/testcafe/bin/testcafe.js but that never got execute permissions:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 * users 207 Oct 26  1985 testcafe-with-v8-flag-filter.js*
-rw-r--r-- 1 * users  59 Oct 26  1985 testcafe.js*
(not sure why they are dated 1985 either??)
I added execute permissions to testcafe.js and now testcafe -v gives 1.1.3
and headless is working.